# How transform a data-frame into spc classes with package "zipfR"?

Tags: r, class, spc

I have a data.frame that represents the frequency of frequency of RT(retweets). I have this type of data.frame:

`data.frame':368 obs.of 2 variables:
$ Var1: Factor w/ 368 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Freq: int  71482 16111 7720 4555 2949 2053 1620 1210 978 775 ...`

I want to use the following comand by "zipfR" package:

`gigp_pos <- lnre("gigp",cost="chisq",method="NLM",rt_pos.spc)`

then I must transform this data-frame into spc object. This type of object needs to express some variables:m,v,N,Vm.

I put:
`Vm<- frq_frq_pos$Freq`
`m<- frq_frq_pos$Var1`

but I don't understand the difference between the variable V and the variable N. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `zipfR` package, but based on ?`lnre` I can't anticipate what you're up to. Please help. What data do you need transformed? What are variables `m`, `v`, `N` and `Vm`? Are you trying to use `lnre.spc`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I must transform all my dataset in spc object, because I want model with lnre command. Then I see with the command ?lnre that m is a integer vector of frequency classes m, Vm is a vector of corresponding class sizes Vm, and finally N, V are total sample size N and vocabulary size V of frequency spectrum. I don't understand the difference between V and N.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new user of zipfR as well but I believe you can use

```
spc(Vm=frq_frq_pos$Freq, m=frq_frq_pos$Var1)
```

Maybe you'll also want to unfactor Var1 -- why is it a factor anyways?

- V = number of unique terms (called 'types' in the package); =sum(Vm)
- N = total number of observations/occurances (called 'tokens' in the package); =sum(Vm*m)
- '`spc`' stands for spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

```
rt_pos = your data.frame
Vm = rt_pos$Freq
m = 1:length(Vm)
rt_pos.spc = spc(Vm, m)
```

you cant use ?spc to see the details

Comment: flguo, this answer looks like it needs more explanation in order to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

N is size of sample (number of tokens), V is its vocabulary (number of types). If for some reasons you want to avoid creating spc object (see below) you can get N and V in an easy way.

```
N <- sum(frq_frq_pos$Freq * frq_frq_pos$Var1)
V <- sum(frq_frq_pos$Freq)
```

A better way is to use `spc` function

```
your.spc <- spc(Vm=frq_frq_pos$Freq, m=frq_frq_pos$Var1)
```

then you won't have to calculate N and V because it is already there in spc object:

```
 N(your.spc)
 V(your.spc)
```

BUT, if you have an access to raw data (I guess it is some text?), then the easiest way to obtain a spc object is a function `text2spc.fnc` (from languageR package):

```
 your.spc <- text2spc.fnc(your.text)
```

Then you can call:

```
 your.spc$Vm
 your.spc$m
 N(your.spc)
 V(your.spc)
```